# How to skip conditions in "Where" clause with multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I"m working on a WinfForms/C# software for automotive key management that's has a SQL query thats searchs in the table like that:

```
DataAdapter = SetAdapter($"SELECT * FROM keylist WHERE MANUFACTOR LIKE @manufactor AND KEYTYPE LIKE @type AND SERVICETYPE LIKE @service AND USER_ID = @_user");
```

So in the begginig I used to use the query directly in the search function but as the project grew, it ended up leaving it without performance, because the query was called directly on the remote server. So I decided to move everything to a list in C # and do the search with lambdas functions.

This is the function with lambda expression:

```
 public List<Key> SearchFilter(string manufactor, string type, string service)
 {
     return _keys.Where(key =>  key.Manufactor == manufactor
                                 && key.Type == type
                                 && key.ServiceType == service).ToList();

 }
```

The problem is:
In the SQL syntax, when you leave one or more fields, it automatically ignores and checks for the other, but when I use Where <> in the LINQ for example, it ends up returning null or items that do not satisfy conditions and returning other objects.

When I leave one or two of the parameters null, it returns no value. By the way, if I use || instead of && it returns undesirable values.

Is there a way to check if the condition is null and skip to the next clause and return only the values that were passed?

Comment: SQL doesn't automatically ignore anything. Moving processing to the client results in *far worse performance* simply because the client is far weaker than the database server and has no indexes to accelerate searches. Even if it did, reading and copying the data over the wire means that the time wasted copying the data can't be used to search it

Comment: `MANUFACTOR LIKE @manufactor` and `key.Manufactor == manufactor` are 2 different things

Comment: So what is the best way to do that?

Comment: I suspect the real problem is a bad query that attempts to perform full-text-search. `LIKE 'abc%'` can benefit from indexes. A statement that searches in the middle or end of the field though, ie `LIKE '%abc%'` will have to scan everything. It would still run faster than copying the same data to the client to search everything though

Comment: @GabrielFrancisco to do *what*? You haven't explained what you want to do yet. What's the actual query? What does `@manufactor` contain? How many records are there in `keylist`?

Comment: If you want to search for specific words you can use [full-text search indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15). These break strings into words and index individual words. These won't help if you want to search for parts of a word, eg for an autocomplete box

Comment: As for LIKE, it's equivalent to `String.StarsWith`, `String.Contains`, `String.EndsWith` or a regular expression.  It acts like `==` only if there are no wildcards in the term it searches.

Comment: But the question is if one or more of the parameters is null, if I put only the @manufactor field for example, I would like all table values that satisfy the "manufactor" value to be returned and ignored "type" and "service"

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, I think I should make several "Where" conditions, one for each condition, that is:

```
return _keys.Where(key => manufactor != string.Empty ? key.Manufactor == manufactor ? key.Manufactor != string.Empty)
            .Where(key => key.Type == type)
            .Where(key => key.ServiceType == service)
            .ToList();
```

You can also "exclude" or "include" filters if there is value to filter as I did with "key.Manufactor".